# Distinguish between user closing form and user closing app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am dealing with the following scenario:

- When user is trying to close one particular form in my application (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> or via dedicated button) I need him to log out when certain conditions are met,
- Therefore I overrode `OnFormClosed` method, check the conditions, if they are met I display a message box and once user clicks OK, he is logged out of my application,
- I am investigating `FormClosedEventArgs.CloseReason` and only apply this logic in situation of `UserClosing`,
- However, when user tries to close the entire application (via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> or Close button in upper right corner), the `CloseReason` is still `UserClosing`, so instead of shutting down the application, he is presented the messagebox and logged out of application afterwards. This is not desired because application shutdown is obviously stronger than log out.

So my question - is there a nice way to distiguish between user closing a form or user closing an entire application? I could probably set some bool flags by overriding `ProcessCmdKey` to distinguish between <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, but that is not very nice and also doesn't solve this issue when clicking the close button.

Comment: Im not sure about this, but perhaps you could catch the app closing event (Application scope and not form scope) and then set a flag on all your forms to disable the form closing logic, before they close?

Comment: Just to (maybe) make it more complicated, do you also want to detect the case where the user is stopping Windows, and try to do something then?

Comment: @RenniePet if I understand your point correctly, then it should be covered by my code already, as the `CloseReason` is `WindowsShutDown` in such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no nice way, you have to detect the user closing your main window *before* the FormClosing events starts firing.  Not a capability that's exposed in Winforms, but you can easily add it by overriding the WndProc() method in your main window's Form class.  You're interested in the WM_SYSCOMMAND message, SC_CLOSE command:

```
    public static bool MainWindowClosing;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x112 && (m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0) == 0xf060) {
            MainWindowClosing = true;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Now you can test that variable in your other classes:

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        if (!Form1.MainWindowClosing && e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
            // Display your dialog
            //...
        }
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
```

You need to set MainWindowClosing back to *false* if you do anything to prevent the user from closing your app.  And I would remiss to not mention that adding a login procedure beyond the highly secure Windows login is a grave mistake that is likely to expose passwords.

Comment: Thanks! Searching for WM_SYSCOMMAND revealed that somebody had to deal with this in our solution previously and there already was a necessary property on our main form. I just proposed minor edit, as  by looking at our code it seems like the flag should be set even in case of WM_CLOSE message.

Comment: No, WM_CLOSE is too late.  That was the entire point of detecting WM_SYSCOMMAND, seeing it *before* WM_CLOSE triggers the FormClosing events.  Don't screw up my post please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any built-in method to do what you want (other than preprocessing system keystrokes). Any closing initiated by the user in the application (except for MDI forms) is going to be `ÙserClosing`.

One workaround could be having your form embedded in another form (with the `Owner` set to the outer form) and check if the inner form closing is with a `FormOwnerClosing` reason (that'd happen if you click the 'X' on the outer form), and check for `UserClosing` on the parent form, instead of the actual form (the inner one), but I'd say that's even less elegant and would split your code around two different forms.